# My first android app always stops in ld player

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

this is my first time creating an android app so i don't know this error either.
It's just that I want to display an xml file on the main screen that I have set up before, but it doesn't work.
here is my code:

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.maytinh

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.maytinh.ui.theme.MayTinhTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00107A"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="math_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.16"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="May tính"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.01" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="ExtraText">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="AC"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="CE"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="%"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.05"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="."
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="@string/marrin"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@string/Button_color"
                android:text="="
                android:textSize="@string/Bt_Text_size" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is logcat

```
2023-06-07 07:08:05.338  7100-7100  System                  com.example.maytinh                  W  ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.maytinh-1/lib/x86
2023-06-07 07:08:05.436  7100-7100  AndroidRuntime          com.example.maytinh                  D  Shutting down VM
2023-06-07 07:08:05.442  7100-7100  AndroidRuntime          com.example.maytinh                  E  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.maytinh, PID: 7100
                                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.maytinh/com.example.maytinh.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2698)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6197)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #45: Error inflating class android.widget.Button
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:433)
                                                                                                        at com.example.maytinh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6701)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2651)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6197)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Drawable com.example.maytinh:string/Button_color2 with resource ID #0x7f0c0001
                                                                                                    Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File #FFDE00 from drawable resource ID #0x7f0c0001
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:757)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:603)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:858)
2023-06-07 07:08:05.442  7100-7100  AndroidRuntime          com.example.maytinh                  E      at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:928)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:4202)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:710)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:101)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:58)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:717)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:785)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                                        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2433)
                                                                                                        at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.setContentView(ComponentActivity.java:433)
                                                                                                        at com.example.maytinh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:18)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6701)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2651)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2759)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1482)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6197)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:892)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:782)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: #FFDE00
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAssetNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.AssetManager.openNonAsset(AssetManager.java:439)
                                                                                                        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:750)
                                                                                                        ... 40 more
```

I'm not very good at this either

just want to display the preformatted xml file

Comment: Can you share the error!

Comment: If your app is crashing, it'll show an error in the logs, along with the sequence of calls that led up to it (the stack trace). This can help you diagnose your problem - e.g. if it's an issue with your XML, it'll probably tell you exactly what line is causing the issue. If you need more help with it, edit your question to include the stack trace (in a code block so it's nice and readable!)